# How to add a search bar to a collection view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

How do you add a search bar to a collection view controller in iOS 12? I realize this should be a simple question but I'm having difficulty finding an example that doesn't look half-baked.

This can either be just using a search bar or a search controller. I don't know what the best approach should be in iOS 12. I would also like to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use a UISearchController. Put the collection view controller into a navigation controller and set the `searchController` of its `navigationItem`. Now the search bar will appear in the navigation bar. You can configure things so that the search bar appears only when the user scrolls the collection view all the way down; that is effectively the same as making the search bar be at the top of the collection view. This is a nice interface and is what Apple expects you to use.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense but haven't trouble making this appear. Do you mean to set the navigation item title view? `self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar`

Comment: No. That's the old way. The `searchController` property, introduced in iOS 11, is a lot cleaner and comes with some great interface behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused, it is a very strange thing to put the `UISearchBar` in the `UICollectionView`. Because the `UICollectionView` the display uses the `UICollectionViewCell`, each `UICollectionViewCell` can be reused.

So I guess you are not going to put in the `UICollectionView`, but search the results through the SearchBar, using the `UICollectionView` to display the results.

Sorry, my network can't upload images. The layout is probably `UISearchBar` and `UICollectionView` in `UIViewController`.

```
- UIViewController
  - UISearchBar
  - UICollectionView
```

In the `UISearchBarDelegate` proxy method, the network request can be executed when the search is triggered, and the data returned by the network request is refreshed on the list.

If you are not very demanding on the layout of the list, you can use `UITableView`, `UICollectionView` needs to set `UICollectionViewLayout` to be slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

In code huh?  Using storyboards all you need to do is add the search bar and connect it to an IBAction outlet.  When it changes you pass the value to a predicate and reload your collection.  Delegate and other Mac Search bar options can be set in code or right in the storyboard.  Sorry I couldn't fully bake it for you!